# build Try-Catch in IEnumerable when reading XML

Tags: c#, xml, try-catch

I am hitting an exception in the XML when running this particular block of code. I have established a try-catch but VS2010 is saying "'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.GetDocumentsData(string)': not all code paths return a value". The exceptions range from null value to XML formatting exceptions. I just need to capture them and will log them into a file (that part of the code is not done yet).

C# code:

```
    private static IEnumerable<object[]> GetDocumentsData(string folderPath = @"filepath")
    {
        try
        {
            return Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.xml")
               .Select(XDocument.Load)
               .SelectMany(file => file.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "FilingLeadDocument").Concat(file.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "FilingConnectedDocument")))
               .Select(documentNode =>
               {
                   var receivedDateNode = documentNode.Elements().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName == "DocumentReceivedDate");
                   var descriptionNode = documentNode.Elements().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName == "DocumentDescriptionText");
                   var metadataNode = documentNode.Elements().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName == "DocumentMetadata");
                   var registerActionNode = metadataNode.Elements().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName == "RegisterActionDescriptionText");

                   return new object[]
  {
       (string)documentNode.Parent.Parent.Elements().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName == "DocumentIdentification"),
       (DateTime?)receivedDateNode.Elements().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName == "DateTime"),
       descriptionNode != null ? descriptionNode.Value.Trim() : string.Empty,
       registerActionNode != null ? registerActionNode.Value.Trim() : string.Empty
  };
               }).ToArray();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        { }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your method should return a value, it means that the Catch block is a block that should return something.
either `IEnumerable<object[]>` ,`null` or you should throw an `Exception` and let someone else handle it. 
Since your catch block preventing the exception to be fly back, you should treat this block as it was outside of the try catch block

**Edit**  - this is a different story
you will have to separate it into foreach, than inside the foreach do the try catch
if the catch will hit, it will write to log and continue to the next one.
(your code is impossible to read, I think you might want to break it down to blocks)

```
 private static IEnumerable<object[]> GetDocumentsData(string folderPath = @"filepath")
        {
            IList<object[]> collection = new List<object[]>();
            foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.xml"))
            {
                try
                {
                    /// do the proccecing here
                    collection.Add(/*your found elements*/);
                }

                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    log.Error("Cant get collection", e);

                }
            }
            return col;
        }
```

**Another solution - please be careful I dont know your code and where the exception thrown**

```
private static IEnumerable<object[]> GetDocumentsData(string folderPath = @"filepath")
        {

                return Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.xml")
                   .Select(XDocument.Load)
                   .SelectMany(file => file.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "FilingLeadDocument").Concat(file.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "FilingConnectedDocument")))
                   .Select(documentNode =>
                   {
                       try
                       {
                           var receivedDateNode =
                               documentNode.Elements().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName == "DocumentReceivedDate");
                           var descriptionNode =
                               documentNode.Elements()
                                           .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName == "DocumentDescriptionText");
                           var metadataNode =
                               documentNode.Elements().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName == "DocumentMetadata");
                           var registerActionNode =
                               metadataNode.Elements()
                                           .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName == "RegisterActionDescriptionText");

                           return new object[]
                               {
                                   (string)
                                   documentNode.Parent.Parent.Elements()
                                               .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName == "DocumentIdentification"),
                                   (DateTime?)
                                   receivedDateNode.Elements().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName == "DateTime"),
                                   descriptionNode != null ? descriptionNode.Value.Trim() : string.Empty,
                                   registerActionNode != null ? registerActionNode.Value.Trim() : string.Empty
                               };
                       }
                       catch (Exception e)
                       {
                           //Log.error("");
                           return new object[] {};
                       }
                   }).ToArray();

        }
```

Comment: How would I do that? I just realized that if I hit an exception, the datagridview does not get populated. I just want to catch and log the exception while still returning my information.

Comment: @clerktech it is really depends on your context, some time you want to return null because the caller method asks `if(GetDocumentsData()!=null)`. I am not sure returning empty collection will meet your requirement, really depends on your code.

Comment: returning the empty collection is not needed. I was going to log the exception but continue to populate the second datagridview with data. is this still possible?

Comment: @clerktech - yes, you can log the error and return null. the caller method will invoke the next one.

Comment: how would I do this? I tried to manipulate the code inside the catch block but intellisense is not liking anything. would it still be "Return new object []"?

Comment: thank you! I am working on it now. I appreciate the assistance. learning XML on my own and new found C# material like the try-catch in an "IEnumerable".

Comment: ok. a little confused. in the try-catch, I am wanting to log the error but keep processing all the XML files in the folder. when returning "null", the second datagridview is still empty.

Comment: that looks awesome. one last question: where does all of my code, from the original post, go into the setup you provided? is this between the "try" curly braces like before?

Comment: I am sorry, you'll have to tweak it a little bit to make it happened.

Comment: @clerktech - I added another option for you

Comment: @ Avi Fatal no worries. I appreciate the lesson being learned here. Makes me a better programmer and for others to learn from my mistakes. thank you for everything.

Answer (score 5):

To fix your actual compilation error, just return an empty `IEnumerable` in the event of an exception:

```
private static IEnumerable<object[]> GetDocumentsData(string folderPath = @"filepath")
{
    try
    {
        return Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.xml")
           .Select(XDocument.Load)
           .SelectMany(file => file.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "FilingLeadDocument").Concat(file.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "FilingConnectedDocument")))
           .Select(documentNode =>
           {
               var receivedDateNode = documentNode.Elements().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName == "DocumentReceivedDate");
               var descriptionNode = documentNode.Elements().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName == "DocumentDescriptionText");
               var metadataNode = documentNode.Elements().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName == "DocumentMetadata");
               var registerActionNode = metadataNode.Elements().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName == "RegisterActionDescriptionText");

              return new object[]
              {
                   (string)documentNode.Parent.Parent.Elements().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName == "DocumentIdentification"),
                   (DateTime?)receivedDateNode.Elements().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName == "DateTime"),
                   descriptionNode != null ? descriptionNode.Value.Trim() : string.Empty,
                   registerActionNode != null ? registerActionNode.Value.Trim() : string.Empty
              };
           }).ToArray();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    { 
        return Enumerable.Empty<object[]>();
    }
}
```

However, I'd question why you are "happy" with these errors -> exceptions are not to be ignored usually. If an exception happens *here*, what do you expect to happen further up the chain?

Comment: I am not "happy" about these exceptions. They will be placed in a log file and sent back to the vendor for correction. I just need to catch them and continue. Thank you for your help! It worked

Answer (score 1):

You get the error because there's no `return` statement in the `catch` block. This is necessary, because if there would be an exception thrown, what would the method have to return?
So, add `return null;` in the `catch` block, and when you use your method elsewhere in your project, check for `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code don't return value in catch block. This is why your code cannot compile.
You should decide what value you want to return from this method when exception was thrown. Or, may be, you should catch this exception in caller method, not here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle errors within the loop and continue processing, you can also use `yield return` inside your `IEnumerable` method to handle each result, similar to the pattern here https://stackoverflow.com/a/32656320/1037948