# Stopping async iterator on exception

Tags: c#, async-await, yield-return, iasyncenumerable

Is it possible to just silently terminate an `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` iterator on exception?

For example, my naive approach was as follows:

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<T2> Map<T1, T2>(IAsyncEnumerable<T1> source, Func<T1, T2> map)
{
    try
    {
        await foreach(var elem in source)
            yield return map(elem);
    }
    catch
    {
        yield break;
    }
}
```

This, however, does not work, because `yield return` is not allowed inside a `try/catch` block. The issue is [tracked](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2949) in dotnet repository, but no fix is proposed so far.

Is there any way to rewrite it without having to forgo compiler-generated iterator?

Note: I would like to catch all exceptions, including ones from underlying iterator (e.g. `TaskCancelledException` from a cancellation token).

Comment: Change the tope answer there to finish up with `if (ret == null) yield break; else yield return ret;`

Comment: @Charlieface the approach in your linked issue handles exceptions inside `map` function, but not from the underlying iterator. Unfortunately this is not enough for my case

Comment: No the `try` surrounds `MoveNext` so will also catch the underlying iterator. Have you tried it?

Comment: I just posted a [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067188/yield-return-with-try-catch-how-can-i-solve-it/76094252#76094252) to the [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067188/yield-return-with-try-catch-how-can-i-solve-it).